# client-server between html and java application

Tags: java, html, sockets, communication

I have a problem.
I need an example of client-server application between a Java application and an html file.
The HTML file should take the touch screen input (tablet) and this should send the touch event (even as a simple string) to a java application which will process this information.
The HTML file will be located on a tablet, while the java application on a PC, both in the same LAN.

Can anyone help me an example of a project? They novice between HTML and JAVA.
Thank you and sorry for my English

Comment: What OS your tablet is running?

Comment: Tablet OS is Android

Comment: PC OS is Windows 10

Comment: My best guess is that your task is to develop a Single-Page-Application. Google's AngularJS ( https://angular.io/ ) , BackboneJS (http://backbonejs.org/ ) are candidates.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very vague.

What you are looking for is called REST. It is a way of communicating over HTTP.

You should look into either DropWizard og Spring boot. These are two java frameworks which support REST. There are a lot of tutorials which are very beginner friendly.

As for the HTML file. You can create a simple `input form` which interacts with your REST methods.

Tutorial with Dropwizard:

https://kielczewski.eu/2013/04/developing-restful-web-services-using-dropwizard/

Tutorial with Spring boot:

http://spring.io/guides/tutorials/bookmarks/

Tutorial for HTML input form:

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp